# MySQL (mariadb) strange VARCHAR WHERE NULL behaviour

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a table like:

```
id    name (varchar)
--------------------------
1     test
2     some
3     NULL
4     test
```

when I query

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name != 'some';
```

I get the result:

```
id    name
--------------------------
1     test
4     test
```

**Why it doesn't return the rows with `name == NULL` ?**

Server Version: 5.5.31-MariaDB-1~squeeze-log - mariadb.org binary distribution (protocol version 10)

Client Version: libmysql - 5.1.66 (mysqli)
Protokoll-Version: 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because comparing with `NULL` results in `UNKNOWN`. You have to use the `IS` operator.

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE name != 'some' 
OR    name IS NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

For `NULL`, you need to use `WHERE name IS NULL` instead of equating it using `==`

You can find more details on the MySQL documentation ( [3.3.4.6. Working with NULL Values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html) )

Searching stackoverflow for "MySQL NULL" yields many identical questions

Answer (score 0):

Because `NULL` is not equivalent with `Empty String`. `NULL` simply does not exist or unknown while `Empty String` exist but a zero-length value. If you want to search including `NULL`. then you can specify it in the condition.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name != 'some' OR name IS NULL
```